mongoose.connect throws ECONNRESET error after running few minutes
Below code I'm using to connect to the database.
mongoose.connect(
    encodeURI(<REMOTE_CONNECTION_STRING>),
    {
        socketTimeoutMS: 0,
        serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 3000
    }
);

// Connect
connectPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('connected', () => console.log('connected'));
    // db.on('open', () => console.log('open'));
    db.on('disconnected', () => console.log('disconnected'));
    db.on('reconnected', () => console.log('reconnected'));
    db.on('disconnecting', () => console.log('disconnecting'));
    db.on('close', () => console.log('close'));

    // Wait till connection is successful
    db.once('open', () => {
        console.log("Database connection successful.");
        resolve();
    })

    // Handle connection failure
    db.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('Database connection error :' + error)
        reject();
    });
});
await connectPromise;

When I run the server, initially it works fine and connecting to database and I'm able to query and all. But after some idle minutes, it throws ECONNRESET error.
Error: read ECONNRESET
Any db options I'm missing here ?
Edit: Adding version details
mongoose v8.6.3
node v20.17.0


The ECONNRESET error is likely related to an idle connection between your application and the MongoDB server. When the connection is idle for too long, the MongoDB server or the network may reset the connection, resulting in the ECONNRESET error.

Hi @RaviChauhan, but it is happening very frequently. Like with in 3 - 4 minutes. Is there any way to keep it alive or increasing the timeout config value ?

Try setting keepAlive: true and reducing keepAliveInitialDelay to 2 minutes, along with increasing socketTimeoutMS to 10 minutes to prevent frequent disconnections.

Along with keepAlive: true and reducing keepAliveInitialDelay, try setting heartbeatFrequencyMS: 1000 for more frequent heartbeats and socketTimeoutMS: 0 to disable socket timeout completely, ensuring the connection stays alive during idle periods.

Updated the question with adding version details @RaviChauhan. As per doc, both keepAlive and keepAliveInitialDelay are deprecated as of mongoose version 7.2.0 and it throws error.

Let me check with in my IDE and provide you proper solution
